# table view selected index method not work (push)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview, selectedindex

there is a table view at my tab bar application' s firs tab. Then when click any row I want to do pushing secondviewController' s view. and there is label. The label's text must be selected row's text. I try this but not enter second tab :S How can I do this??? Also at secondViewController class have 3 view.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

SecondViewController  *detailViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
// ...
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
NSUInteger row2 = [indexPath row];
denemelik=row2;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
detailViewController.enyakinfirma.text= [ws2.CustomerName objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; 
NSLog(@"kontrol2 %@",ws2.CustomerName);

[detailViewController release];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `enyakinfirma` is your `UILabel` that you want to populate with the text. You cannot assign text to the label before the label is actually created and loaded. And that happens later, after you push the new view controller.

Thus you need to create a separate `@property` in order to keep track of this text you need:

```
// SecondViewController.h
@interface SecondViewController {
    NSString *customerName;
}    
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *customerName;
@end
```

When you create the view controller you assign this property:

```
detailViewController.customerName = ...;
```

And in your view controller's `viewDidLoad` method you update the text.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    // ...
    enyakinfirma.text = self.customerName;
}
```

Comment: Is that so secondViewController class have another 2 view? Not pushing secondView. :(

Comment: I tried your solution but it still not work..Do you have any idea about this??